# printf("%2$*11$s", ...) what is this formation means

Tags: c++, c, format, printf

it use like in c11/c++?:

```
printf("%2$*11$s",...)
```

It is come from a elf file, this file using printf() to operate like `mem[4]=mem[2]+mem[1]`. You can refer from this https://ctftime.org/task/5042 (it is a reverse CTF question).

To my point, I know the $ is use to specify the position of which var but no reference notice that one block can have two $.

also, I cannot find any func about $ in format except location.

so, I will be grateful if anyone can tell me it is meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`n$` is an extension defined in POSIX to select which argument to print. This is called *Parameter field*.

[printf format string - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Parameter_field)

Actually this question is about using two `n$` in one format specifier. Let me examine with small examples...

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%1$*3$s\n", "a", "b", 10, 20);
    printf("%1$*4$s\n", "a", "b", 10, 20);
    printf("%2$*3$s\n", "a", "b", 10, 20);
    printf("%2$*4$s\n", "a", "b", 10, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GuJMBUY4txG68f1t):

```
         a
                   a
         b
                   b
```

It looks like `%n$*m$s` means "print the `n`-th argument using the width specified by the `m`-th argument". The final `s` has the meaning of `s` in `%s`.

Answer (score 3):

See the POSIX specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and family.

It is used to allow internationalization (I18N) and localization (L10N) of messages, so that the arguments to the `printf()` call can be printed in arbitrary orders.  When you use an *`n$`* notation for any element of the format string, you are supposed to use it for all elements.  You are also supposed to identify all arguments from 1 to the maximum number referenced — and the types must match what the format expects too.

An example:

```
printf("%2$ is %1$allowed to fly to %3$\n", "not ", "Superman", "School");
printf("%3$ is %1$allowed to fly to %2$\n", "", "Superman", "School");
```

Those produce:

```
Superman is not allowed to fly to School
School is allowed to fly to Superman
```

Often, the format string will come from a variable so that the order may be varied according to the local requirements.  The formatted data will also usually be in variables too.  Using hard-coded strings as in these examples is abnormal.